# How to looping through multiple arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby. I am creating a rails platform where I have encountered the following issue:
I have my first array, which for the sake of simplicity I call 'capital' as:
`capital = [A,B,C,D]`. I have a second array `small = [a,b,c,d]`. The elements of `small` have many to one relationship with the elements of the `capital`, as:

```
capital 
has_many:small
```

These two are linked through two tables in my database, so that valid combination of these arrays can be printed by

```
capital.each do |x|
     small.each do |y|
        puts x,y
     end
end
```

which prints out valid combinations of x,y as defined in the database. This works perfectly fine.

Now, here is the issue: I have a third array `array_3`, which contains some combinations of the elements of `capital` and `small`, as:

`array_3 = [(A,c), (C,d), (D,b)]`

I want to print all valid combinations of elements of `capital` and `small` as defined in the database, such that the combination is not present in `array_3`. How do I go about it?

Comment: Could you format the question properly ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
capital = %w(A B C D)
small = %w(a b c d)
array_3 = [%w(A c), %w(C d), %w(D b)]

capital.product(small) - array_3
#=> [["A", "a"], ["A", "b"], ["A", "d"], ["B", "a"], ["B", "b"], ["B", "c"], ["B", "d"], ["C", "a"], ["C", "b"], ["C", "c"], ["D", "a"], ["D", "c"], ["D", "d"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
capital.each do |x|
  small.each do |y|
    puts x,y unless array_3.include?([x,y])
  end
end
```

Comment: I have post d answer by modifying your solution for all combination..bdw 1+ for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is for all combination of `capital` and `small` which exists in `array_3`

```
capital.each do |x|
  small.each do |y|
    puts "[#{x}, #{y}]" unless array_3.exclude?([x,y])
    puts "[#{y}, #{x}]" unless array_3.exclude?([y,x])
  end
end
```

Check the Code in console:

```
> small
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
> capital
 => ["A", "B", "C", "D"] 
> array_3
 => [["A", "c"], ["C", "d"], ["D", "b"], ["A", "A"], ["C", "C"], ["a", "C"], ["b", "A"]]

> capital.each do |x|
>   small.each do |y|
>      puts "[#{x}, #{y}]" unless array_3.exclude?([x,y])
>      puts "[#{y}, #{x}]" unless array_3.exclude?([y,x])
>   end
> end
```

**Output:**

```
=>[b, A]      # [small, capital]
[A, c]        # [capital, small]
[a, C]        # [small, capital]
[C, d]        # [capital, small]
[D, b]        # [capital, small]
```

**Note:** You can use `if array_3.include?` instead of `unless array_3.exclude?` which will return the same result.

For your more info about [**`exclude?`**](http://apidock.com/rails/String/exclude%3F) and [**`include?`**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) as you are new in Ruby. ;)